# React Js: update one item from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

in my database i have  opening Time table where i have shifts of each day in the week,
when i try to modify the opening time of one day ,opening Time of others day they are deleted

---

this my code to update my state data

```
 async handleChange(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;


   await this.setState({
      opening_time: {
        ...this.state.opening_time,

        [this.state.day]: [['1', name == '0' ? value : this.state.opening_time[this.state.day][0][1], name == '1' ? value : this.state.opening_time[this.state.day][0][2]],(name == '2' || name == '3')? ['1', name == '2' ? value : this.state.opening_time[this.state.day][1][1], name == '3' ? value : this.state.opening_time[this.state.day][1][2]]:['0']]


      }
    });

    this.props.setData({ opening_time: JSON.stringify(this.state.opening_time) })



  }
```

```
  setData(data) {
    this.setState({ data: { ...this.state.data, ...data } })
```

```
  async send() {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    await callApi('post/' + this.state.id, this.state.data, 'PUT') .then(res=>{console.log(res,"yrt")
    }).catch(error=>{ this.setState({visible: "echec"})})



  }
```

this is my opening Time format

```
{"Mon":[["1", "08:00", "12:15"],["1", "14:14", "23:23"]],"Tue":[["0"],["0"]],"Wed":[["0"],["0"]],"Thu":[["0"],["0"]],"Fri":[["0"],["0"]],"Sat":[["0"],["0"]],"Sun":[["0"],["0"]]}
```

can somebody help me ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the previous state to update state instead directly using this.state inside the state.
refer React documentation [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

in your code, you can rewrite the code like below

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
      opening_time: {
        ...prevState.opening_time,

        [prevState.day]: [['1', name == '0' ? value : prevState.opening_time[prevState.day][0][1], name == '1' ? value : prevState.opening_time[prevState.day][0][2]],(name == '2' || name == '3')? ['1', name == '2' ? value : prevState.opening_time[prevState.day][1][1], name == '3' ? value : prevState.opening_time[prevState.day][1][2]]:['0']]


      }
    }));
```

```
 setData(data) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ data: { ...prevState.data, ...data } })_
```